# ImageView will not show up

Tags: android, imageview

In OnCreate:

```
svMaster = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);     //Only layout in XML file
    svMaster.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
    Display display = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    height = display.getHeight();
```

...

```
initializeGUI();
svMaster.removeAllViews();
svMaster.addView(llMaster);
```

In initializeGUI():

```
llMaster = new LinearLayout(this);         //Only direct child of scrollview
LinearLayout llFirstScreen = new LinearLayout(this);  //First layout added to llMaster;
                                                      //It's size is that of one screen
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpMaster = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpFirstScreen = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);

    llMaster.setLayoutParams(lpMaster);
    llMaster.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    llFirstScreen.setLayoutParams(lpFirstScreen);
    llFirstScreen.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue2);
    llFirstScreen.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Here's my code pertaining to the ImageView:

```
ImageView ivWeather = new ImageView(this);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams ivWeatherParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
            (Scale(80), Scale(80);

ivWeather.setImageResource(R.drawable.sunny);
Log.d("ImageView loading?", "I hope so");
ivWeather.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
ivWeather.setLayoutParams(ivWeatherParams);
ivWeather.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);      //This is code I tried
ivWeather.setFocusable(true);               //when it wouldn't show up
ivWeather.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);    //...
ivWeather.invalidate();                     //...
```

...

```
llFirstScreen.addView(ivWeather);
Log.d("ImageView loading?", "I hope so");
llMaster.addView(llFirstScreen);
```

...

I have added TextViews with no problem to llFirstScreen, and I am wondering why ImageView
won't show up. I tried even adjusting llFirstScreen's height to WRAP_CONTENT instead of the screen's height. All that did was shrink the layout to the two TextViews. It's as if it never added the ImageView. The Logs I put in check out, so I know the code is running.
Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing your LinearLayout.LayoutParams from Scale(80), Scale(80) to something like LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT or something? I've never seen Scale(int) used. If that is a custom method can you post it?

Comment: scale = this.getApplication().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
//Convert to dps
 private int Scale(int i) {
  i = (int)((float)i*scale + .5f);
  return i;
 }
This is a method to convert integers to dps

Comment: lollol
you made me realize that I initialized the scale variable AFTER I use the custom scale method which requires the scale variable...duh
thanks